# Jquery/ajax function acting up, possibly CSS related

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I am new to web design and I am working on a site. I followed a tutorial in order to make a pop-up login/register box using a script, and the problem is that it's not really working. I think it's related to z-index, but I have tried changing it to different values (even 1500 and above) to no avail.

Also, for some reason, the "close"/"x" button has stopped working. Can you please explain to me what I've done wrong?

Here's the code (html) and CSS here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round|Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginLink").click(function( event ){
           event.preventDefault();
           $(".overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
     });

    $(".overlayLink").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).attr('data-action');

        $("#loginTarget").load("ajax/" + action);

        $(".overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
    });

    $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 27 && $(".overlay").css("display") != "none" ) {
           event.preventDefault();
            $(".overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
        }
    });
});
</script>




</head>

<body>
<!--- LOGIN OVERLAY ---->
<div class="overlay" style="display: none;" >
        <div class="login-wrapper">
                <div class="login-content" id = "loginTarget">
                        <p>Loading...</p>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
<!--- SOCIAL INTEGRATION --->

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>







<!--- TOP SECTION + MENU ---->

<header role="banner">
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="index.htm">
                    <div>
                        Home
                        <span>The most honest reviews!</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <div>
                        Reviews
                        <span>Placeholder</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">PC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Consoles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Software</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact.htm">
                    <div>
                        Contact
                        <span>Contact us!</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/forum">
                    <div>
                        Forum
                        <span>Connect with others</span>
                    </div>
                    </a>
            </li>
            <li id = "loginbutton">
                <a href="controlpanel.php">
                    <div>
                        User
                        <span>Placeholder</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="login.php" class="overlayLink" data-action="login-form.html" id="loginLink">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="register.php" class="overlayLink" data-action="registration-form.html">Register</a></li>
                        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>


<body>
<!--- LOGIN OVERLAY ---->


<section class = "container">

<h1>HONEST REVIEWS</h1>
<ul>
    <li><a href="login.php" class="overlayLink" data-action="login-form.html">Log-in</a></li>
    <li><a href="register.php" class="overlayLink" data-action="registration-form.html">Register</a></li>
</ul>
</section>


<article>

<div class ="textreview">
<h2>First Review</h2>
<h3>How Homeworld revolutionized 3D RTS</h3>
<h4>By Andrei Negut</h4>

<div class="videocontainer"> 
<video width="640" height = "480" controls id="video">
<source src = "media/An Introduction to Homeworld Remastered Collection.mp4" type= "video/mp4">
</video>
</div>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam nec tempor nulla. Quisque luctus neque quis porta viverra. Nam vel feugiat mauris. Mauris sagittis ipsum nec nisi gravida, vehicula iaculis tortor placerat. Duis tincidunt auctor ex, vitae tristique est dictum non. Quisque placerat facilisis enim et aliquet. Proin suscipit urna in metus laoreet pretium. In porttitor malesuada tincidunt. Curabitur accumsan nisi at felis aliquet, id accumsan mi scelerisque. In ullamcorper ultrices lacinia. In aliquet lorem ligula, et scelerisque orci semper sit amet. Donec id aliquet purus, non faucibus est.
</p>
Quisque pharetra eros dolor, eget ornare dolor porttitor eu. In et tempus dolor. Sed metus lorem, cursus in accumsan ut, sodales eu enim. Quisque commodo finibus ex id scelerisque. Duis iaculis porttitor nulla eu dignissim. Cras est eros, fermentum eu luctus sit amet, egestas non lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla facilisi. Sed aliquet nibh leo. Morbi eu nisi orci. Aenean ut auctor tellus. Integer ut purus vel quam commodo elementum. Integer scelerisque est eget elit consequat congue.
<p>
Duis convallis lectus sed rutrum cursus. Maecenas at tempor mauris, vel vulputate lorem. Morbi maximus ipsum metus, at euismod risus viverra eget. Nullam commodo ex vel nisl eleifend sagittis. Nunc sed rhoncus justo, a porta sem. Ut non augue eget nulla tincidunt finibus pellentesque eu risus. Praesent vitae velit nec libero mattis feugiat. Fusce a lorem ullamcorper, vehicula risus a, euismod lacus. Nam at facilisis orci. Vivamus egestas, metus et viverra congue, nunc dolor volutpat massa, eu laoreet tortor nisi eu felis. Sed vitae dignissim nisi. Sed quis sagittis odio. Maecenas posuere, quam ut hendrerit convallis, risus orci lobortis tellus, non commodo sem felis eget quam. Donec lobortis maximus erat, vitae tempus ex vestibulum vel. Donec ornare neque risus, eu eleifend ex efficitur vel. Donec hendrerit tincidunt venenatis.
</p>
Quisque nec enim auctor, vestibulum lorem eu, luctus massa. Vestibulum mollis posuere nibh, vel imperdiet libero pellentesque in. Donec ac pulvinar dolor, eget aliquet ante. Pellentesque aliquam justo non arcu pharetra scelerisque. Ut semper risus id sem fermentum pulvinar. Duis convallis lobortis justo, non fermentum tortor pretium eget. Nullam et cursus tellus. Sed eu finibus nunc. Pellentesque vestibulum nibh libero, at gravida augue feugiat vel. Vestibulum nec libero aliquam, aliquet elit et, vestibulum justo. Mauris tincidunt nibh vitae nunc placerat imperdiet. Donec ut nisi eget ligula mollis molestie vel sit amet quam.
<p>
In et velit fringilla, fermentum tortor nec, efficitur purus. Aenean et ipsum vitae mauris semper tristique. Vestibulum ac scelerisque ipsum. Nulla facilisi. Nulla venenatis lorem et laoreet tempus. Curabitur mattis ex quis dolor sagittis feugiat. Quisque fringilla urna sed nunc maximus, quis luctus justo accumsan. Mauris a malesuada erat. Mauris sed ipsum vitae est tempor gravida sed non mauris. Phasellus auctor sapien id posuere placerat. Cras id tortor a nisi fermentum molestie eget pretium metus. Integer et ultrices mi. 
</p>
</div>


 <!-- <div class = "controlbar" id ="controlbar">
 <button class = "videobutton" onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
   <button class="videobutton"onclick="makeSmall()">360p</button>
  <button class="videobutton" onclick="makeNormal()">480p</button>
  <button class="videobutton" onclick="makeBig()">720p</button>
  <button class="videobutton" onclick="makeHD()">Original</button>
</div> 


<script> 
var video = document.getElementById("video"); 

function playPause() { 
    if (video.paused) 
        video.play(); 
    else 
        video.pause(); 
} 


function makeSmall() { 
    video.width = 360; 
    controlbar.width = 360;
} 

function makeNormal() { 
    video.width = 640; 
    controlbar.width = 640;
}

function makeBig() { 
    video.width = 720; 
    controlbar.width = 720;
} 

function makeHD(){
    video.width = 1080;
    controlbar.width = 1080;
}

</script>  --->



</article>

<aside>

<p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam nec tempor nulla. Quisque luctus neque quis porta viverra. Nam vel feugiat mauris. Mauris sagittis ipsum nec nisi gravida, vehicula iaculis tortor placerat. Duis tincidunt auctor ex, vitae tristique est dictum non. Quisque placerat facilisis enim et aliquet. Proin suscipit urna in metus laoreet pretium. In porttitor malesuada tincidunt. Curabitur accumsan nisi at felis aliquet, id accumsan mi scelerisque. In ullamcorper ultrices lacinia. In aliquet lorem ligula, et scelerisque orci semper sit amet. Donec id aliquet purus, non faucibus est.

Quisque pharetra eros dolor, eget ornare dolor porttitor eu. In et tempus dolor. Sed metus lorem, cursus in accumsan ut, sodales eu enim. Quisque commodo finibus ex id scelerisque. Duis iaculis porttitor nulla eu dignissim. Cras est eros, fermentum eu luctus sit amet, egestas non lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla facilisi. Sed aliquet nibh leo. Morbi eu nisi orci. Aenean ut auctor tellus. Integer ut purus vel quam commodo elementum. Integer scelerisque est eget elit consequat congue.

Duis convallis lectus sed rutrum cursus. Maecenas at tempor mauris, vel vulputate lorem. Morbi maximus ipsum metus, at euismod risus viverra eget. Nullam commodo ex vel nisl eleifend sagittis. Nunc sed rhoncus justo, a porta sem. Ut non augue eget nulla tincidunt finibus pellentesque eu risus. Praesent vitae velit nec libero mattis feugiat. Fusce a lorem ullamcorper, vehicula risus a, euismod lacus. Nam at facilisis orci. Vivamus egestas, metus et viverra congue, nunc dolor volutpat massa, eu laoreet tortor nisi eu felis. Sed vitae dignissim nisi. Sed quis sagittis odio. Maecenas posuere, quam ut hendrerit convallis, risus orci lobortis tellus, non commodo sem felis eget quam. Donec lobortis maximus erat, vitae tempus ex vestibulum vel. Donec ornare neque risus, eu eleifend ex efficitur vel. Donec hendrerit tincidunt venenatis.

Quisque nec enim auctor, vestibulum lorem eu, luctus massa. Vestibulum mollis posuere nibh, vel imperdiet libero pellentesque in. Donec ac pulvinar dolor, eget aliquet ante. Pellentesque aliquam justo non arcu pharetra scelerisque. Ut semper risus id sem fermentum pulvinar. Duis convallis lobortis justo, non fermentum tortor pretium eget. Nullam et cursus tellus. Sed eu finibus nunc. Pellentesque vestibulum nibh libero, at gravida augue feugiat vel. Vestibulum nec libero aliquam, aliquet elit et, vestibulum justo. Mauris tincidunt nibh vitae nunc placerat imperdiet. Donec ut nisi eget ligula mollis molestie vel sit amet quam.

In et velit fringilla, fermentum tortor nec, efficitur purus. Aenean et ipsum vitae mauris semper tristique. Vestibulum ac scelerisque ipsum. Nulla facilisi. Nulla venenatis lorem et laoreet tempus. Curabitur mattis ex quis dolor sagittis feugiat. Quisque fringilla urna sed nunc maximus, quis luctus justo accumsan. Mauris a malesuada erat. Mauris sed ipsum vitae est tempor gravida sed non mauris. Phasellus auctor sapien id posuere placerat. Cras id tortor a nisi fermentum molestie eget pretium metus. Integer et ultrices mi. 
</p>
</aside>




<!--- LOGIN OVERLAY ---->
<div class="overlay" style="display: none;">
        <div class="login-wrapper">
                <div class="login-content" id = "loginTarget">
                        <p>Loading...</p>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>





<footer>
<small>Copyright © Andrei Negut 2015 </small>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Honest-Reviews/1498677940381771?fref=ts" data-width="150" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS

```
* {margin: 0;padding: 0;outline: none;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;}
*:after, *:before { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section {  display: block;}
html {font-size: 100%;height: auto !important;height: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;}
.clear {display: block; }
.clear::after {clear: both;content: ".";display: block;height: 1px;visibility: hidden;}


html{
height:100%;
background-image: url("https://gearboxsoftwarecom.s3.amazonaws.com/images/_/20150220/6c640b6aaa926cd0e110cc11dd353ac217c30cbe.jpg");
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
z-index: -1;
}

body{
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
z-index: 1;
height:100%;
}
/* image background, just in case
img.background {

        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 3480px;


        width: 100%;
        height: auto;


        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
}

        @media screen and (max-width: 3840px){
            img.background{
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -1920px; }
}

*/

/*OVERLAY*/
a.close {
    background-color: rgb(204,204,204);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-size: .8em;
    padding: .2em .5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.25rem;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    right: 1.25rem;

}

    a.close:hover {
        background-color: #1bc5b3;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

/*
*    LOG-IN BOX
*/
div.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;


}

    div.overlay > div.login-wrapper {
        align-self: center;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 6px;
        width: 450px;

    }

        div.overlay > div.login-wrapper > div.login-content {
            background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
            border-radius: 2px;
            padding: 24px;    
            position: relative;

        }

            div.overlay > div.login-wrapper > div.login-content > h3 {
                color: rgb(0,0,0);
                font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
                font-size: 1.8em;
                margin: 0 0 1.25em;
                padding: 0;
            }
/*
*    FORM
*/
form label {
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    margin: .75em 0;    
}

    form input[type="text"],
    form input[type="email"],
    form input[type="number"],
    form input[type="search"],
    form input[type="password"],
    form textarea {
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        border: 1px solid rgb( 186, 186, 186 );
        border-radius: 1px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
        display: block;
        font-size: .65em;
        margin: 6px 0 12px 0;
        padding: .8em .55em;    
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        width: 90%;
    }

    form input[type="text"]:focus,
    form input[type="email"]:focus,
    form input[type="number"]:focus,
    form input[type="search"]:focus,
    form input[type="password"]:focus,
    form textarea:focus,
    form select:focus { 
        border-color: #4195fc;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 8px #4195fc;
    }

        form input[type="text"]:invalid:focus,
        form input[type="email"]:invalid:focus,
        form input[type="number"]:invalid:focus,
        form input[type="search"]:invalid:focus,
        form input[type="password"]:invalid:focus,
        form textarea:invalid:focus,
        form select:invalid:focus { 
            border-color: rgb(248,66,66);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 8px rgb(248,66,66);
        }

form button {
    background-color: #50c1e9;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-size: .85em;
    padding: .55em .9em;
    transition: all 400ms ease;    
}

    form button:hover {
        background-color: #1bc5b3;
        cursor: pointer;
    }



input:invalid { color: red; } //if I want to change it later

/*LOGINFORM */

/*BUTTONSTYLE*/


/*BUTTONSTYLE END*/

h2 {
    color: rgb(34,34,34);
    font-size: 2.2em;   
    font-weight: 200;
    margin: 0 0 24px 0;
}

/*BANNER + MENU*/

    header {
        background: linear-gradient(to left,rgba(255, 33, 0, 1) 0,rgba(139, 20, 14, 1) 100%);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    header > nav > ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

        header > nav > ul > li {
            flex: 0 1 auto;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: relative;
            transition: all linear 0.1s;    
        }

            header > nav > ul > li:hover {
                background: black;
            }
            header>nav>ul>#loginbutton{
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            right:0;
            border: 2px dashed;
            border-color:black;
            padding-bottom: -2;
            border-radius: 180px;
            border-width: 1px;
            }

            header > nav > ul > li a + div {
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255, 33, 0, 1) 0,black 100%);
                border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
                box-shadow: 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                display: none;
                font-size: 1rem;
                position: absolute;
                width: auto;
            }

                header > nav > ul > li:hover a + div {
                    display: block;
                }

                header > nav > ul > li a + div > ul {
                    list-style-type: none;  
                }

                    header > nav > ul > li a + div > ul > li {
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                    }

                        header > nav > ul > li a + div > ul > li > a {
                            color: white;
                            display: block; 
                            font-size: .75rem;
                            letter-spacing: 1.5px;
                            padding: .25rem 1.5rem;
                            text-decoration: none;
                            text-transform: uppercase;
                        }

                            header > nav > ul > li a + div > ul > li:hover > a {
                                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);  
                            }

            header > nav > ul > li > a {
                align-items: center;
                color: #fff;
                display: flex;
                font-size: 1.55rem;
                font-weight: 200;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
                max-width: 130px;
                padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
                transition: all linear 0.5s;
            }

                header > nav > ul > li > a > div > span {
                    color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
                    display: block;
                    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                    font-size: .7rem;   
                    font-style: italic;
                    line-height: 1rem;
                    max-width: 260px;
                }


  header > nav > ul > li > a {
    max-width: 500px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.8rem;
  }

  header > nav > ul > li > a > div > span {
      margin: 4px 0 0;  
  }




@media (min-width: 990px) {
  header > nav > ul > li > a {
    max-width: 500px;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
  }

  header > nav > ul > li > a > div > span {
      margin: 4px 0 0;  
  }
}
/*Banner end*/

/*Footer*/

footer{

background: linear-gradient(to right,black,rgba(139, 20, 14, 1) 100%);
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
display: block;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
color: white;
bottom:0;
clear:both;
margin-bottom:0;
}


/*VIDEO AND BUTTONS*/


.videocontainer{
float:right;
height:480px;
width: 640px;
border-style: hidden;
border-radius: 5px;
display:block;

}

.controlbar{
position:relative;
display:flex;
background-color: grey;
opacity: 0.5;
width: 640px;
align-items:center;
flex: 1;
}

.videobutton{
position:relative;
border: none;
background-color: grey;
cursor:pointer;
border-style: none none none solid;
border-width: 1px;
font-weight: 700;
flex:1;
}


/*PAGE FORMATTING */
aside{
display:flex;
float:right;
border-style: solid;
width: 15%;
height:auto;
overflow: scroll;
background-color: white;
opacity: 0.7;
}
article{
display:flex;
width: 77%;
margin-right: 1,5%;
float:left;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0.7;
color: white;
}
#contactsection{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
#contact{
        align-self: center;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 6px;
        width: 450px;
}

article.textreview{
display:block;
float:left;
}
.container{
padding: 90px 0;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: black;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
z-index: 1500;
}

h1{
color: yellow;
}





.username_avail_result{
    display:block;
    width:180px;
}
.password_strength {
    display:block;
    width:180px;
    padding:3px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#333;
    font-size:12px;
    backface-visibility:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.password_strength.weak{
    background:#e84c3d;
}
.password_strength.normal{
    background:#f1c40f;
}
.password_strength.strong{
    background:#27ae61;
}
.password_strength.verystrong{
    background:#2dcc70;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

The erratic behavior can only be seen on a web server, so I hosted it here: http://andreinegut.zz.vc/License/index.htm

NOTE: the overlays behave differently on the index page and on the contact page. This is why I suspect it's about z-index, but I'm not 100% sure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is the php call executing properly? have you tried printing the results? Because when i click login i see an error on the console and i think that's preventing the javascript/css to be executed properly.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a bad question but how can I check whether it's being executed properly? If it weren't, wouldn't I be redirected to an error?

Comment: open chrome dev tools, and click on login. You can see on the right bottom corner the warning/error appearing. You can also try right in the console to call your jquery methods to toggle/untoggle the login overlay to see if it's everything working properly without calling any php file.

Comment: Oddly, when I'm opening the site in Chrome and using the dev tools, there's no error other than a warning related to the facebook plugin. Strange?

Comment: i've tried messing up your code a bit and the login overlay needs a higher z-index. Also, when you click on login the overlay that covers all the page needs to be 'display: none' or else you can't click anywhere

Comment: I did try messing with the z-index, even setting it to 1500 and above. Still, nothing. Also, I'll try updating the overlay in the .css and see what happens.

Comment: I am honestly lost. I did whatever I could, messed with the z-index for every single element within div.overlay, tried to redo the "close" button function but it's still not working. I would really appreciate some help since I must be missing something terribly obvious